# Azure SQL Server connection error 121 (Semaphore Timeout) with Power BI

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, oledb, ado

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Server from PowerBi I'm getting an error code 121 (Semaphore timeout), exact message is:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)

I spent a lot of time trying to diagnose network related issues, without success. What is making this even more strange is that if I choose OLE DB provider, then I'm able to connect without issues. So, same client computer, same network, same Azure SQL Server, same PowerBi desktop version.

Although there is a workaround I´d like to understand what is going on, because the default provider for PowerBI doesn't work and it makes things more "confusing" for our users to have to go and connect using OLE DB instead of SQL Server.

Any idea what might be going on? This was working a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: SQLNCLI was deprecated in 2012 and doesn't support anything after SQL Server 2014; you really shouldn't be using it any more. Use the latest OLEDB or ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to connect Azure SQL server to Power BI with SQL Native client, I got the same error. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16), SQL Server Native Client version 11.0 only supports up to SQL Server 2014, meaning it does not support SQL Server 2019. This is the reason for the error when connecting to Azure SQL Server from Power BI. You should use the OLEDB or ODBC provider, or you can directly connect Azure SQL Server to Power BI using the following option:

[image]

Enter the server name and database name, and click OK as shown below:

[image]

Select the database option, enter the SQL Server credentials for authentication as mentioned below, and click Connect:

[image]

The server will connect successfully without any errors, as shown below:

[image]